# Is it possible to load handlebar template with script tag? Or define handlebar templates programmatically in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Simply enough I do not want to define all my handlebar templates in my html file

I tried this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nav-bar" src="template.handlebar"></script>
```

But this did not work. Can I not define templates my template programmatically or even just load handlebar files so that I can reuse and also I feel it makes things a bit more maintainable.

I tried just loading them with ajax and appending them to the head, this works fine I can see it there but ember.js doesn't read it after ember has already been loaded and the templates are not defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Or define handlebar templates programatically in Ember.js

You can define templates programmatically by using `Ember.Handlebars.compile`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/wxrxT/:

```js
Ember.View.create({
    personName: 'Dr. Tobias Fünke',
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello {{personName}}')
}).append();​
```

Or you add compiled templates to `Ember.TEMPLATES` array, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/58tFP/:

```js
Ember.TEMPLATES['myFunkyTemplate'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello {{personName}}');

Ember.View.create({
    personName: 'Dr. Tobias Fünke',
    templateName: 'myFunkyTemplate'
}).append();​
```

---

I would recommend to use some tools like *Richard Millan* stated. Also take a look at [interline/ember-skeleton](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton) which offers support for compilation of templates.

Comment: Ah yes! this is the kind of stuff I was looking for kind of

Comment: Ember CLI is another great option.

Comment: The syntax has slightly changed in the latest version of Ember (v1.8 at time of writing) to {{view.personName}}. Checkout my jsbin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/soqore/2/edit

Answer (score 8):

You can also patch Ember View to load templates on get

```
Em.View.reopen({
    templateForName: function(name, type) {
        if (!name) { return; }

        var templates = Em.get(this, 'templates'),
            template = Em.get(templates, name);

        if (!template) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'templates/%@.hbs'.fmt(name),
                async: false
            }).success(function(data) {
                template = Ember.Handlebars.compile(data);
            });
        }

        if (!template) {
            throw new Em.Error('%@ - Unable to find %@ "%@".'.fmt(this, type, name));
        }

        return template;
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Since Ember 1.0.0-pre.3 this solution probabaly no more work (maybe can be migrated to recent Ember)

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with recent Ember.js?

Comment: Note that synchronous requests are now considered obsolete: http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Answer (score 5):

So since I still wanted separate files for my templates and I didn't want to define them in strings in the javascript I hacked this together last night

It is a synchronous lazy loader, it loads all the templates first, then ember and the rest of my code,

```
        //fake function so that every loads fine will get redefined in application.js
        function initializeApp(){}

        function loadTemplates(){
            var arg = arguments[0],
                next = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
            if(typeof arg != 'string'){
                arg()
            }else{
                var scriptObj = document.createElement('script');
                scriptObj.type = 'text/x-handlebars';
                $(scriptObj).attr('data-template-name', arg.replace('.handlebars', '').substring(arg.lastIndexOf('/')+1))
                $.get(arg, function(data){
                    scriptObj.text = data;
                    document.head.appendChild(scriptObj);
                    if(next.length > 0) loadTemplates.apply(this, next);
                });
            }
        }

        function loadScripts() {
            var script = arguments[0],
                scriptObj = document.createElement('script'),
                next = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
            scriptObj.type = 'text/javascript';
            scriptObj.src = script;
            scriptObj.onload = scriptObj.onreadystatechange = (next.length > 0) ? function(){loadScripts.apply(this, next)} : function(){$(document).ready(function() {initializeApp()})};
            document.head.appendChild(scriptObj);
        }

        function loadApp(obj){
            loadTemplates.apply(this, obj.templates.concat(function(){loadScripts.apply(this,obj.scripts)}))
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            loadApp({
                templates:
                    [
                        '/javascripts/views/templates/nav-bar.handlebars',
                    ],
                scripts:
                    [
                        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initializeGoogleMaps',
                        '/javascripts/lib/bootstrap.js', 
                        '/javascripts/lib/rails.js', 
                        '/javascripts/lib/ember.js',
                        '/javascripts/application.js',
                        '/javascripts/views/nav_bar.js',
                    ]
            })
        }
```

EDIT: I cleaned it up and made it work properly only testing in chrome though

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you will need to precompile your templates first. This will also allow you to include all your templates within one file.

- If you are using Rails, you can use the [ember-rails gem](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) to do it for you.
- Otherwise you can follow [these instructions on how to precompile handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html)

Later on, you will need to include the javascript file.

```
<script src="path/to/compiled/templates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I don't believe you can compile Ember.Handlebars w/ standard handlebars tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you load your templates into the DOM before loading Ember, then you don't need to compile or register your templates.  Ember will come along after and do it for you.

Here is an article showing how:

http://weboriented.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/loading-handlebars-templates-in-ember-using-curl-js/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, inside your Ember view/component:

```
var viewClass = Ember.View.extend({ templateName: this.get('contentTemplate') });
var view = this.createChildView(viewClass);
var html = view.renderToBuffer().buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so all the answers are a bit outdated. With [Ember CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com/) templates are auto loaded by naming convention as require.js modules. It's a bit odd, since you write proposed ES6 import syntax and the build transpiles it into require.js syntax, but it works really well.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, and yes, you can do it without usage of another another another tool, just using ember.js and nothing else. i did it like this:

1) html code. note that all handlebars files need to be loaded before using any of them. here, its just one file named handlebars.js

```
<body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.8.1.min.js"></script>    
  <script src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

2) this file handlebars.js contains the following, using the compiler of ember

```
var src = "Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>";
Em.TEMPLATES["say-hello"] = Em.Handlebars.compile(src);
```

3) and then inside your app.js file, just use it as it were available (which it is):

```
var hu = Em.View.create({
    templateName: "say-hello",
    name: "Allô", 
    mouseDown: function() {  
    window.alert("hello world!");

  }
});

hu.appendTo("body");
```