# How to instantiate the Ember Application when using precompiled templates with grunt-ember-templates

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, gruntjs

(This questions is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15877005/647991), but now I have moved to `grunt-ember-templates` instead of `grunt-contrib-handlebars`)

I am trying to split my ember.js handlebars templates in several files, in order to make the code base more manageable. I am using `grunt-ember-templates`, configured as follows:

```
ember_templates: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            templateName: function(sourceFile) {
                return sourceFile.replace(/app\/templates\//, ''); // <%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/
            }
        },
        files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/templates.js': [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.hbs'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a `dist/scripts/templates.js` as expected, which my client is happily loading. The `templates.js` looks like this:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["accounts"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    ...
```

This looks fine to me: the templates are saved in `Ember.TEMPLATES` array, with expected keys. There is even an `application` key, further down the generated `templates.js` file:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["application"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
```

Which is coming from `templates/application.hbs`:

```
<section class="toolbar">
</section>
<section class="main_section">
  <nav>
      ...
  </nav>

  {{ outlet }}

</section>

<div class="modal small hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      ...
</div>
```

Still, I am getting this error when `templates.js` is loaded (which is actually embedded inside `scripts.js`, see below my `index.html`):

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You specified the templateName application for <App.ApplicationView:ember312>, but it did not exist.
```

What does this criptical error mean and how can I get rid of it?

This is my `Ember Application`:

```
this.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    VERSION: '1.0.0',
    ready: function () {
        console.log('App version: ' + App.VERSION + ' is ready.');
    }
});
```

This is my `ApplicationView`:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});
```

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-styles.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </head>
  <body>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

    <!-- My templates used to be here, but now they are in templates.js -->

      <div class="pagination">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/handlebars.1.0.rc.3.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/ember-data.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your `App.ApplicationView` look like?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `templateName: 'application'` from your `ApplicationView`? I use grunt-ember-templates and in my `ApplicationView` I don't specify the `templateName` and it finds my precompiled application template.

Comment: That indeed removes the error message, but the application does not get instantiated.

Comment: I see a `<div id="ember312" class="ember-view"></div>` created by ember, but it is completely empty.

Comment: Here is a JSBin with a compiled application handlebars template and no `templateName`: http://jsbin.com/imuhiy/1/edit is this different than what you have?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27874/discussion-between-gonvaled-and-c4p)

Answer (score 2):

For the record: my problem was solved by changing the order in which the javascript files are loaded.

The `templates.js` must be loaded *after* ember is loaded.

I thought that ember needs the templates defined before loading, but this is actually completely wrong: since the templates are stored in `Ember.TEMPLATES`, ember must be loaded **before** the templates are. Then the templates can be loaded, and then the application can be created.

The reason why I did not find this bug before is that ember is not complaining at all in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `template:` instead of `templateName:`, and it seems to work fine:

```
template: Ember.TEMPLATES['application']
```

There may be a better way to do this. But this will at least get you unstuck.