# Using ember.js without the script tag for template

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

Oh you, God of the dynamic language, You who learned Vim and use Open Source, hear my prayer.

I would like like very much to use **Ember.js** to create my application. But I can't. Dear God, I am an unworthy Java developer and I use those impure software called "IDE" that help me autocomplete and check my code (heresy I know). Dear God, the particular IDE I use (an obscure and unknown IDE called Eclipse, something that nobody ever use) tend to choke on those holy and divine `<script>` tags that contain my handlebars templates. Those tag break the autocompletion and the code check because the heretic IDE think its javascript. Now, since I am an unworthy person, I something make mistake that I'd like my IDE to pick up, and thus the current situation make very sad.

In order to have the IDE help me write HTML again, I would very much like, dear God, to put those templates in an external file. I would then be able to instruct the impure IDE to parse the text as HTML and then continue my miserable life as a developer that lean on his tools. Ideally, those file would end up in `.html` because my horrible environment actually use the file extension to guess the content of a file (can you believe such a scandalous thing). But I guess something that ends up in `.handlebars` would be enough for me sinner.

So, what I am asking, oh You of the Cloud, is to tell me the incantation to recite to make all that happen. Tell me, what must I add to my `app.js` defined so

```
(function(Ember, $) {

    var App = Ember.Application.create();

});

})(Ember, jQuery);
```

my `index.html` written so

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Holy app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/underscore-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my external `application.html` containing the following

```
<div id="prayers">
    <p>
        Oh you who know all UNIX terminal command<br>
        You who shall not support any legacy code and tools<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        Make it so that this text appear in my browser<br>
        So that all of us Java and C# sinner<br>
        See the light and reveal in your dynamic way<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        Pardon our sin when we believe that using automatic refactoring tool is useful<br>
        And free us from our reliance on static typing to make less mistake<br>
    </p>
    {{holyAnswer}}
</div>
```

so that the content of `application.html` find its way in `index.html`?

I know of the `App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.create()`, and I have heard of `Ember.Handlebars.compile()` but my feeble mind does not know how to make it work or how I should use it. My impure way already include compilation, so I may use javascript build tool if such is the burden that you ask of me.

Please, you of the Web, you of the Open Standards, help me in those troubled times.

EDIT

Dear god, I know of this question [Is it possible to load handlebar template with script tag? Or define handlebar templates programmatically in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274391/is-it-possible-to-load-handlebar-template-with-script-tag-or-define-handlebar-t?rq=1) , but the answer does not tell me how to make it so that my template become the equivalent of the unnamed `<script>` tag that are in the holy `ember.js` example. This template seem to be the application root, and I do not know how to tell `ember.js` to use it.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to precompile your templates externally.** As you are a Java Developer, this Maven [plugin](https://github.com/kawasima/handlebars-maven-plugin) might be good for you. **Use this plugin to compile your templates into one JS File**, that contains all your templates in compiled form. Then all you need to do is include this JS File in your html. I myself compile my templates into a file called 'templates.js'. In this case your html would be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Holy app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/underscore-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/templates.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a spin (and stop posting weird question at 2 in the morning)